# Modifying new code to support PHP5.3

Tags: php, wordpress, php-5.3, php-5.5

I'm using Roots.io wordpress starter theme. It's coded for PHP 5.5 but the server I'm posting the site on is running PHP 5.3

I need to change this code to be supported by the PHP on the server, but don't know how.

```
function asset_path($filename) {
    $dist_path = get_template_directory_uri() . DIST_DIR;
    $directory = dirname($filename) . '/';
    $file = basename($filename);
    static $manifest;

if (empty($manifest)) {
    $manifest_path = get_template_directory() . DIST_DIR . 'assets.json';
    $manifest = new JsonManifest($manifest_path);
}

if (WP_ENV !== 'development' && array_key_exists($file, $manifest->get())) {
    return $dist_path . $directory . $manifest->get()[$file];
} else {
    return $dist_path . $directory . $file;
}
}
```

The issue is in this line:

```
return $dist_path . $directory . $manifest->get()[$file];
```

The `[$file]` is confusing PHP  I think but no idea how to modify this. Any tips? If more code is needed please let me know.

Comment: Try this `$man = $manifest->get();
return $dist_path . $directory . $man[$file];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to split that return as requesting an index from a method call I think started getting supported in 5.4.

Try splitting it out.

```
$val = $manifest->get();
return $dist_path . $directory . $val[$file];
```

For reference this is know as array dereferencing. You can find more information about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Comment: like I said in my comment )

Comment: Indeed. Look like we were writing at the same time.

Comment: Thanks. This eliminates the error, but the resources are loading with duplicate domain name. so I'm getting resource requests to "http://domain.com/domain.com/path_to_resource". The DB is good so it has to be somewhere in here. Any ideas?

Comment: @sixli Then do some dumps of the variables and see what they are. You might not need one of them in the concat, but that depends the package you're using.